# Detect mouse drag and direction using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, drag, mousedown

I am trying to detect the mouse direction when dragging the mouse. When the mouse button is down and the user drags the mouse, I want the text to change to left or right depending on the mouse drag direction.

Here's my code.

```js
var divOverlay = document.getElementById ("div");

var dragged = false
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function () { dragged = false })
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function () { dragged = true })
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {

    
        if (dragged == true && e.pageX <= 0) {
            direction = "left"
        } else if (dragged == true && e.pageX >= 0) {
            direction = "right"
        }
        
        divOverlay.innerHTML = direction;
        
        oldx = e.pageX;
})
```

```css
#div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

I don't think I'm too far off but I can't workout what I am doing wrong so I need some help.

Comment: Why are you storing `oldx` if you're not using it?

Comment: Do you want the text to change on `mouseup` or `mousemove`?

Comment: @Apollo79 Whatever is quickest. I just want to detect if the user is dragging left or right

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I was using it but in an attempt to try and figure out my issue, I removed it from the if statement.

Comment: @Juan-man OK, I think there are enough solutions by now... I suggest you to use `pointer...` events instead of `mouse...` events, for they fire on touch **and** mouse moves, "downs", and "ups"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. It just needed a minor tweak.

```js
var divOverlay = document.getElementById ("div");

var dragged = false
var oldX = 0;
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) { oldX = e.pageX; dragged = false })
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function () { dragged = true })
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {

    
        if (dragged == true && e.pageX < oldX) {
            direction = "left"
        } else if (dragged == true && e.pageX > oldX) {
            direction = "right"
        }
        
        divOverlay.innerHTML = direction;
        
        
})
```

```css
#div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `oldX` to the position checking. You also need to initialize it.

```js
var divOverlay = document.getElementById("div");

var dragged = false
var oldX = 0;

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  dragged = false;

  // set start position of drag
  oldX = e.pageX;
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
  dragged = true
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
  // compare drag end position with start position
  if (dragged == true && e.pageX <= oldX) {
    direction = "left"
  } else if (dragged == true && e.pageX > oldX) {
    direction = "right"
  }

  divOverlay.innerHTML = direction;
});
```

```css
#div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but the drag result is a bit random. I can drag right a couple of time and the text will change to left.

Comment: `oldX` needs to be set on `mousedown`, otherwise the logic would make no sense

Comment: It measures the position of the `mouseup` event versus the last one, and determines left or right from that.

Answer (score 0):

Having a separate function to handle the relative direction of the mouse on the X axis is more likely something suitable for what you would like to do. Instead of trying to update variables, remove the eventListener once the mouse is released.

See below as an example:

```js
    const body = document.body;
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const directionTag = document.getElementById("direction");

  const moveFunc = function (e) {
    let direction;
    if (e.movementX < 0) {
      container.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      direction = "left";
    } else if (e.movementX > 0) {
      container.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      direction = "right";
    }
    if (typeof direction !== "undefined") {
      directionTag.innerHTML = direction;
    }
  };

  body.onmousedown = function () {
    body.addEventListener("mousemove", moveFunc);
  };

  body.onmouseup = function () {
    body.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveFunc);
  };
```

```css
#container {
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">This will change when you hold down</div>
  <p id="direction">Unset</p>
</body>
```